# How to delete a user from Azure AD B2C using the portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure portal under Azure AD B2C -> Users,  there are two users listed both of which I added while running some of the AD examples.  I want to delete both users however the delete button is disabled.  How to enable the button and delete the users please?

Edit:  I want to remove the user from my tenant directory and any apps they are associated with.  If the user is associated with other tenants I don't want to touch that configuration.

Under roles and administrators I am shown as "Global administrator".

This is a paid Azure subscription.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know how you created the user in the b2c tenant ?

Comment: What happens if you try to use microsoft graph api or powershell to delete the users?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity They were added as a result of a user signing up to use an application.

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of how you are trying to delete the user and have you tried to delete the test user in Azure AD tenant?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity screen cap added.

Comment: I tried to repro it, but I was able to delete the user . Can you please cross-check your role as a Global administrator to the b2c tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you are logged in with the user that is selected in your screenshot? Because this is the only way I am able to reproduce the button being disabled.

Even if you are looking at a B2C directory, you will also have the "normal AAD" users in this list, which are used to manage the directory. This way it could look like you have a user which signed up using a B2C user journey, when in fact it was not.

Comment: > This way it could look like you have a user which signed up using a B2C user journey, when in fact it was not.

I think your answer is correct however I expect to be able to delete the entry since it is just an authoriziation for the user to log into a given application.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case this is not just a single application. You would lock yourself out of the whole B2C directory, which is not really what you want.